# Selenium and Java : Import excel to UI and validate the data in the columns in UI

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, testng

We need to import data(Excel sheet)from desktop to our Ui using a button in the UI. Then validate that the column values in excel matches with the UI.We have around 10,000 records and 10 columns in the excel and UI. We are using selenium, java , maven , testng .

Comment: So do you have a question? Have you tried anything? What worked? What did not?

Comment: so whats your query ? how to upload Excel in UI ? or how to compare ? . U have not provided any details. be specific to query !!!

Comment: How to upload excel in UI ?

Comment: If I know how to upload a file I can add the compare as well

Comment: I got it. Can do this by parsing the imported file and formatting its content to match queue data and then comparing it.